# How to use same database transaction in separate thread with Play Framework 2.2

Tags: hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick

From play's [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAsync):

> Because of the way Play 2.0 works, the action code must be as fast as
>   possible (ie. non blocking). So what should we return as result if we
>   are not yet able to generate it? The response is a promise of result!

So I shouldn't be doing database calls directly inside of the action. This now confuses me when I look at [Plays JPA documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaJPA):

> Every JPA call must be done in a transaction so, to enable JPA for a
>   particular action, annotate it with @play.db.jpa.Transactional. This
>   will compose your action method with a JPA Action that manages the
>   transaction for you

This leaves me a little bit confused. If I follow the documentation, I shouldn't block an action thread with a database call. But if the action is what's creating and managing the database transaction, aren't I losing that transaction by sending the work to an actor, or somehow offloading the work to another thread? I mean, I'm new to scala and play, but I just don't see how the transaction would follow into separate threads. Does anyone have an  explanation, or a way that I should be doing this? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a piece of the puzzle, read under "Highly synchronous" here: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

So, yes, you would want it to be non-blocking but if you cannot have that because of JPA/JDBC etc. then you can configure play like you would with the regular Java web containers - a thread pool with lots of threads. It won't give you all that play can give but it might very well be good enough for you.

You could also create a specific thread pool/execution context and run the JPA/JDBC stuff only on that and keep the rest of your server non blocking.

Comment: I like your second suggestion, to have pool/execution context for JPA/JDBC. Would you be able to extend your answer with code, how to do that?